# Have to download Energia code multiple times for the code to update using MSP430F5529 Launchpad

Tags: arduino, launchpad, energia

I'm a beginner in robotics, so I just started playing around with my MSP430F5529 Launchpad. Ever since the first time I started using my launchpad, it seems like I have to click on the 'Download' button of my code in Energia multiple times for it to really update my code. This is getting really annoying since it's really confusing whether the code is not being updated because there is indeed a bug in my code, a problem in my circuit, or because it's just somehow not being updated right away for some mysterious reason.

Has anyone ever encountered such similar situation before? I'm not sure if my launchpad is faulty or if I'm just doing something wrong since I'm a beginner.

Comment: I'm almost certain there's nothing wrong that requires multiple downloads. I don't know the tools your using, but: Do they reset your circuit after they've finished uploading and verifying the uploaded image? Do you give them enough time to do that?

Comment: hi @Marcus, I'm not using anything sophisticated since I'm a beginner. I've been just playing around with very basic, simple LED circuits but even a simple code to update the Pin or print out something to the Serial Monitor, I have to click on the 'Download' button in Energia multiple times for it to really reflect that new change to the code I've made.